# Intermittment websocket errors (1006)

Tags: node.js, websocket

I currently have a Node application opening websocket connections with an external source and streaming data.
Running locally it has no issues, works as expected and keeps connections open to stream and process events. However, when deployed to k8s (EKS) it seems to intermittently close connections with code 1006, and I'm completely stuck for ideas on how to solve this. I've refactored the implementation numerous times and still finding the same issue, i.e. works locally fine but not deployed on cluster. Worth nothing I have multiple pods doing similar processes with web sockets, however they're connecting to different sources - so it seems to just be this one provider when deployed. As per the providers documentation I'm keeping the connection alive if idle with pings but it still seems to close.

My understanding is that 1006 is a low level error that represents an abnormally closed connection, but not entirely sure why this would be happening when the other pods are not having issues.

I know this sounds relatively vague but I'm stuck on how to go about trying to solve this, any suggestions to explore or tips would be greatly appreciated! Has been a very frustrating one.